# Win 270 electoral college votes

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

You are the electoral strategist for a sudden late entrant in the 2020 US presidental election.

**Your task**: print out the names of states* your candidate will win, totalling at least 270 electoral college votes.

### Background

Each state (and Washington DC) in the US system has an arbitrary number of "electoral college votes". A candidate has to win a majority of the 538 votes available, so at least 270 votes.

The number of votes for each state is:

`[['Alabama', 9], ['Alaska', 3], ['Arizona', 11], ['Arkansas', 6], ['California', 55], ['Colorado', 9], ['Connecticut', 7], ['Delaware', 3], ['Florida', 29], ['Georgia', 16], ['Hawaii', 4], ['Idaho', 4], ['Illinois', 20], ['Indiana', 11], ['Iowa', 6], ['Kansas', 6], ['Kentucky', 8], ['Louisiana', 8], ['Maine', 4], ['Maryland', 10], ['Massachusetts', 11], ['Michigan', 16], ['Minnesota', 10], ['Mississippi', 6], ['Missouri', 10], ['Montana', 3], ['Nebraska', 5], ['Nevada', 6], ['New Hampshire', 4], ['New Jersey', 14], ['New Mexico', 5], ['New York', 29], ['North Carolina', 15], ['North Dakota', 3], ['Ohio', 18], ['Oklahoma', 7], ['Oregon', 7], ['Pennsylvania', 20], ['Rhode Island', 4], ['South Carolina', 9], ['South Dakota', 3], ['Tennessee', 11], ['Texas', 38], ['Utah', 6], ['Vermont', 3], ['Virginia', 13], ['Washington', 12], ['Washington DC', 3], ['West Virginia', 5], ['Wisconsin', 10], ['Wyoming', 3]]`

### Input

None

### Output

A list (or similar) containing just the names of the states in your winning strategy. If a string, there must be separators between state names. States must be capitalised as in the list provided above.

You must not output anything other than valid state names and separators. The number of states in your strategy is up to you.

### Rules

You may not use any external (or built-in) list of US state names. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

This is code golf. Shortest code in bytes wins, with the electoral college score as a tie-breaker.

Since there is no input, your code can be a program/script/statement rather than a function.

If you are using space as a separator, then you can't include any states with spaces in the name. Or you would have to do something like enclosing each state name in double quotes. (A separator has to be something that could be used to automatically split the string up into the correct elements.)

`*` For the purpose of this challenge, Washington DC is considered a state.

Comment: [Related (Put together a Senate majority)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132428/36445)

Comment: Probably too late now, but I reckon it would've been interesting to have a scoring system that incentivised a high vote tally as well as a low byte count (something like `bytes/votes`, perhaps).

Comment: Yeah, that might have been interesting. Also, printing the abbreviations might have opened up other interesting challenges.

Comment: I just tightened the rules slightly to clarify that you mustn't produce any extraneous output. (Just in case anyone was thinking of infinite monkeys...)

Comment: That would be already a standard loophole, as far as I remember.

Comment: _You may not use any external (or built-in) list of US state names_ ~> I think this is a borderline [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11228/58563). I suspect that Brotli has most (if not all) the states hard-coded in some internal dictionary. But I'm not supposed to know that, and I'm not even supposed to know that Charcoal uses Brotli under the hood.

Comment: If there are no states containing spaces in our output can we use a space as the delimiter?

Comment: Does case matter here? Can output be entirely uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: @Shaggy "States must be capitalised as in the list provided above." is pretty clear.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sure. Curious how that helps you?

Comment: @Arnauld What does "I'm not supposed to know" mean in this context? There's no problem using a language that has a built in list of state names. Directly making use of that list would be against the rules of this challenge.

Comment: ...saves one byte from my Jelly submission.

Comment: What I mean is that some of the existing answers (including mine) are using a language whose string compression method is based on a compression library that includes at least some of the US states in its internal dictionary. So they are indirectly using a list of US state names, even if the language doesn't explicitly include such a list. The problem is that it's rather tricky to detect that. (The only reason why I decided to dig into Brotli's source code to find out for sure is that I was puzzled by how well Charcoal is compressing some state names. I was not aware of that when I answered.)

Comment: Oh, how interesting. More of a grey area than I had realised.

Comment: [Related (Output the number of Electoral Votes one state has)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75125/46076)

Comment: "arbitrary number" ?

Comment: Thanks, just did some reading. Less arbitrary than I realised: each state gets a proportional number of voters, plus 2.

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal),  <s>52 ... 45</s>  42 bytes (270 votes)

A list of states that optimizes the compression with Brotli.

```
”}∧J⟧´⪫3⎚>↘≡ＶＮb7>¹l↙⁵Þ7/…ξ⌕↑τc<y\MΦＧＣ＆⸿Dρ~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWQAm/9jaGFyY29hbP//4oCdfeKIp0rin6fCtOKqqzPijpo@4oaY4omh77y277yuYjc@wrls4oaZ4oG1w543L@KAps6@4oyV4oaRz4RjPHlcTc6m77yn77yj77yG4ri/RM@Bfv///y1j)

#### Output

```
Texas       
Pennsylvania
Georgia     
Illinois    
Washington  
Indiana     
California  
Arizona     
Michigan    
Virginia    
Florida     
New York
```

#### Node.js script

The initial list was found with the following Node.js script that shuffles the 30 most efficient states, extracts the shortest leading sub-list with a score greater than or equal to 270, joins it with `\r` and invokes the Brotli compressor on the resulting string.

It was optimized some more by shuffling the most promising sub-list to find an order offering the best compression.

```javascript
let states = [ ['Alabama', 9], ['Alaska', 3], ['Arizona', 11], ... ];

states =
  states.map(a => [a[0], a[1], a[1] / a[0].length])
  .sort((a, b) => b[2] - a[2])
  .slice(0, 30);

const zlib = require('zlib');

let bestLen = 1 / 0, bestScore = 1 / 0,
    list, score, str, pack;

while(1) {
  for(let i = states.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [ states[i], states[j] ] = [ states[j], states[i] ];
  }

  for(
    let n = 1;
    (score = (list = states.slice(0, n)).reduce((p, c) => p + c[1], 0)) < 270;
    n++
  ) {}

  str = list.map(s => s[0]).join('\r');
  pack = zlib.brotliCompressSync(Buffer(str));

  if(pack.length < bestLen || (pack.length == bestLen && score <= bestScore)) {
    bestLen = pack.length;
    bestScore = score;
    console.log(bestLen, bestScore, str.split('\r').join('\\r'));
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the `console.log(bestLen = pack.length, bestScore = score, str.split('\r').join('\\r'))` syntax extremely worrying at first glance...

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Doing important assignments within a `console.log`?... What's wrong with that?!?... :-p

Comment: I'm not sure whether that makes the results worse here, but `Math.random() - 0.5` is not a transitive nor an anticommutative comparer and is unlikely to produce all permutations with similar probabilities, and according to a statistical analysis on a random blog, it's especially terrible on Chrome, and I assume that extends to V8 and to Node. (random information: I had C++ programs segfault with maximal optimization with a comparer that turned out not to be commutative in a rare edge case)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate That shouldn't matter much in that case. This method is especially bad for a single pass. But here, each iteration is shuffling the result of the previous one. (Also, we can't try all 30! ~= 2.65*10^32 permutations anyway.)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Anyway, I've switched to Fisher-Yates as it can only be better, and is also _much_ faster. Thanks!

Comment: Ugh, you're outgolfing me in Charcoal now? Whatever next... (Sadly I didn't notice your answer, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered writing my hand-crafted answer.)

Comment: Looks like my downfall was using Ohio and Utah; the other states seem much more compressible. Just replacing those two with longer states reduces my byte count from 59 to 46...

Comment: Just printing those two states uncompressed saves me 8 bytes! Ridiculous...

Comment: @Neil I think the reason is that neither Ohio nor Utah are in [the internal dictionary of Brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli/blob/master/c/common/dictionary.c).

Comment: @Neil After a closer review of Brotli's dictionary, I can confirm that it contains all the states I'm using ([as I was suspecting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204488/win-270-electoral-college-votes/204495#comment485098_204488)), either as-is or in lower case.

Comment: Bah, I found a big flaw in my search technique - I was searching on comma separated strings and then switching to newlines for output. But that change makes a whole world of difference - for example it costs 8 bytes on your list.

Comment: Besides, is Pennsylvania really on brotli's dictionary? (I can't seem to find it, and it's long)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Yes, it's stored at offset 75412.

Comment: It turns out that Massachusetts and Tennessee compress better than Arizona and Indiana. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>68</s> 66 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), 271 votes

```
.•2Y±e1¸Zí¼³sçj†Êè”šʒÕʒ½‘ε-нUeC·ûÝì£…
õ%î!¯aàáè˜3ÒƵLweh³•#`„€¢…Œ»™
```

Outputs the following 12 states newline-separated, totaling 271 votes:

```
California,Florida,Georgia,Illinois,Indiana,Michigan,Ohio,Pennsylvania,Texas,Utah,Virginia,New York
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AYEAfv9vc2FiaWX//y7igKIyWcKxZTHCuFrDrcK8wrNzw6dq4oCgw4rDqOKAncWhypLDlcqSwr3igJjOtS3QvVVlQ8K3w7vDncOswqPigKYKw7Ulw64hwq9hw6DDocOoy5wzw5LGtUx3ZWjCs@KAoiNg4oCe4oKswqLigKbFksK74oSi//8)

If builtins were allowed, we could have used the dictionary for **27 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), 270 votes**

```
”‡Â†éŠ§›ÕïÁ–Û—Ñ—ïŽŽ‡¹¢ÇŸÏžÏ
```

Outputs the following 13 states space-delimited, totaling exactly 270 votes:

```
California Texas Florida Pennsylvania Illinois Ohio Michigan Georgia Virginia Washington Tennessee Massachusetts Indiana
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AUgAt/9vc2FiaWX//@KAneKAocOC4oCgw6nFoMKn4oC6w5XDr8OB4oCTw5vigJTDkeKAlMOvxb3FveKAocK5wqLDh8W4w4/FvsOP//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
.•2Y±e1¸Zí¼³sçj†Êè”šʒÕʒ½‘ε-нUeC·ûÝì£…
õ%î!¯aàáè˜3ÒƵLweh³• # Push compressed string "california florida georgia illinois indiana michigan ohio pennsylvania texas utah virginia"
  #                 # Split it on spaces
   `                # Push them all separated to the stack
    „€¢…Œ           # Push dictionary string "new york" (which are both English words)
         »          # Join all strings on the stack by newlines
          ™         # And title-case each word
                    # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

”‡Â†éŠ§›ÕïÁ–Û—Ñ—ïŽŽ‡¹¢ÇŸÏžÏ
                    # Push the dictionary string "California Texas Florida Pennsylvania Illinois Ohio Michigan Georgia Virginia Washington Tennessee Massachusetts Indiana"
                    # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why:

- `.•2Y±e1¸Zí¼³sçj†Êè”šʒÕʒ½‘ε-нUeC·ûÝì£…\nõ%î!¯aàáè˜3ÒƵLweh³•` is `"california florida georgia illinois indiana michigan ohio pennsylvania texas utah virginia"`;
- `„€¢…Œ` is `"new york"`;
- and `”‡Â†éŠ§›ÕïÁ–Û—Ñ—ïŽŽ‡¹¢ÇŸÏžÏ` is `"California Texas Florida Pennsylvania Illinois Ohio Michigan Georgia Virginia Washington Tennessee Massachusetts Indiana"`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>59</s> <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 41 bytes

```
”}∧I⊗⪫σ³»α“"⸿u↙¦Ｃ^±Ｗ)ＲLκ&⁰Ｙ2Ｅ¬«]f“ＷN+'|⁺≕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsJADEWvIl3pwhO4FBQXlS6KRZhNGGMnGBJIxqqnH0N3n/8eLxewrMCtDUZSt92IX/AkN7KZhCDJhZlEKb6ecqEZJMkZNXDAAUX8xwus6onV6BFjAi8kc9Vwr/jZ3NVeSY7A9FRb1R7cIZe3Y62RHqOD7ojd7tBa2y/8Bw) Link is to verbose version of code. Simply the compressed string for `Texas\nVirginia\nIllinois\nMichigan\nGeorgia\nPennsylvania\nFlorida\nWashington\nNew York\nCalifornia\nMassachusetts\nTennessee`; total 270 votes.

This solution was found with the help of a Python 3 program that randomly selected voting states and took the length of the resulting string. It then tracked the number of times each state appeared in the strings that were less than a certain cutoff length, initially 60, but gradually reduced to 45 as I optimised the input.

Optimisation consisted both of creating a list of frequently used states and removing infrequently used states from the list thus allowing more shuffles to be performed.

Eventually I got to the point where each shuffle always had the states California, Florida, Georgia, Illinois, Michigan, New York, Pennsylvania and Texas, and four of the six states Arizona, Indiana, Massachusetts, Tennessee, Virginia and Washington. At this point I could generate all 15 combinations of 12 states and just had to shuffle the states around in the hope of getting a short answer. Shuffling script:

```python
import brotli
import itertools
import random
import sys

bigstates = ['California', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Illinois', 'Michigan', 'New York', 'Pennsylvania', 'Texas']
smallstates = ['Arizona', 'Indiana', 'Massachusetts', 'Tennessee', 'Virginia', 'Washington']

while True:
 for states in itertools.combinations(smallstates, 4):
  states = bigstates + list(states)
  for j in range(100):
   random.shuffle(states)
   if len(brotli.compress('\n'.join(states).encode("ascii"))) < 39:
    print(states)
    sys.exit()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVGxTsNADN3zFRZLElFFRWUBwYCQQAxFDBUIAcM1cRKXi12dr7Tl50OuSWm29yz7@fl5vfe18KxtqVmL87B04i1FAyOPzotYPRac4UKaI9O9RtGSKvXGo8ItfMT3xlIpjsnEE4gfrDgqDvARxVV99claYiENeE55TZXhgJ9xC@/ivgN@QWbd2x8zKC1wZzT@irQx1o723Tn6Fe5luSDTw7lRNXm9UfRe@3FmVEUM5JU6J4Pum9GauPLCnXi0rckiLNwGryPozoBhE/EpiiyXZklsPAlrMvIzgcu0G4N/d6dkzsGS@qRnadcTtFdBtgu0wuRiOj2MDvlmWm/K0uJoAKgEi5z0/wke1q47KIk/Oc5WQnzszZBzKTA5M5oTnaVpCjcwuzqow9oRj21AeGGGO/JJ2rZ/) The script also found the following shuffles with the same byte count:

```
Print("Texas\nTennessee\nVirginia\nPennsylvania\nWashington\nCalifornia\nMichigan\nMassachusetts\nNew York\nGeorgia\nFlorida\nIllinois");
Print("Texas\nVirginia\nMichigan\nIllinois\nGeorgia\nPennsylvania\nFlorida\nWashington\nTennessee\nMassachusetts\nNew York\nCalifornia");
Print("Texas\nGeorgia\nTennessee\nVirginia\nIllinois\nPennsylvania\nMichigan\nWashington\nCalifornia\nNew York\nMassachusetts\nFlorida");
Print("Texas\nNew York\nVirginia\nPennsylvania\nWashington\nFlorida\nMassachusetts\nGeorgia\nCalifornia\nTennessee\nMichigan\nIllinois");
```

Previous 50-byte solution:

```
”}∧UV↔ΦＪU№ＥIＧ➙eêPn¡Ｆ{⦃←στ⸿Ｍ⊕!⪫¹Ｐ？Ｍξ⁹#<″⊘bh%0ＲＺ⌈⧴↑·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxCgJBEAS/Ihdp4AuMRFAUlAtEETYZ1vWuceiBWTk9P7@umlZ1dezFo4mW0jr4mDZtIvOogxASeEaOxgwGHtNLcuBKFDfzn92qgoZKD@k5uZjfA9dqjmuVm2TefVd7xB6d1IsTKvmVS8fbKP9wlzynsZktSinzQT8) Link is to verbose version of code. Simply the compressed string for `Pennsylvania\nWisconsin\nTexas\nCalifornia\nIllinois\nNew York\nFlorida\nGeorgia\nMichigan\nVirginia\nArizona\nNew Jersey`; total 271 votes.

I started off with the best value states, Texas, California, Florida, Ohio, New York, Illinois, Georgia, Michigan, Pennsylvania, Virginia and Arizona, plus Iowa to make up the numbers. I then tried various permutations of states to find out which ones Charcoal compressed best; moving Ohio, Illinois and New York to the end worked best. (There are 12! possibilities so I'm not trying them all.) I then tried switching Arizona and Iowa with Indiana and Utah, taken from @SurculoseSputum's answer; Arizona made no difference but Utah saved a further byte.

Edit: Saved 8 bytes by printing Utah and Ohio literally instead of trying to compress them. Saved a further byte by using New Jersey and Wisconsin instead of Utah and Ohio. (This did mean reordering the states again for optimal compression. Colorado, 
Indiana, Maryland, Massachusetts, Minnesota, Mississippi and Missouri and also work instead of Wisconsin.)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 106 bytes, 271 votes

```python
print"California,Florida,Georgia,Illinois,Indiana,Michigan,New York,Ohio,Pennsylvania,Texas,Utah,Virginia"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoJAEEbhqxjqqbwCiYYCsFATyoks7B8nM2R2g3L6dS3fK77tyNH0XMrm0Ny0LFjMFUwXMcfMdA3ma@1OBGpI1OkMVqYer4iVlYbwOU3mbxojjG5BNR2y8x@5hy8nemSO9ERl6mtK@QE)

Picks the states with the best votes/name length ratio.

Turns out this is the shortest possible combination of states to achieve at least `270`, as shown in [this DP program](https://tio.run/##dVPvj9pGEP3uv2J0@RCsMxUmpemhUqk61OaScle1aU4VQtViD3iKvYt21wZS5W@/zO46ti9q0XFinue9efPDx4stlJw@PRkrLJrFev3yp1JsRSVeJnCzScDH5uDCVyHU9FFJF6dpCxyENMIw8p0HbkVJO6UluaTZLGCqVFrkqlO9VVJiZimrLWOvPbbEUpyExq7Wz0yi3MlMA@sXVHrvddNQ6w0TiDj@1od3uShUH5UlSUXO2XQSEJmTGJq/UyfRGX/3vI93KG2dHS4MfO@BX1VNpuUHZCVIYldvJfSlFDJ38pMWMUZkRW3QWtNXXVFW0F7Ivo8V8TiMsmLAJWPc3/FInSWHqVrTIEtJGxyFkd3jVrf7mrVAI/K@x3s8wRtRHU1Bunfu0LeoDbpm0x5b4ZkyNdA6wV9KH/qF3CttC7gVWvGovfnZAF@KQ2gpeHsoyGmlYXYPh5KX5Q8trP9B417JLvwNpTSXshHhkNoN/l6oHOHOtHMOVv9Q9XMXNwP4KxPv0U3aIPbreI9nv/ZXwdifVhTdvD6grnjEHf0D8QEGR2lAHgXPUu6tt55Ov8JgedtxH9FYGAiEUT2SyZQ0JPulPl5UxXRP3ETREhbwr39B59Aoi8BvF/g4CTHJEJpPUfQCKqwUfcQcNJq6tCZaOb5/tCOZgy0QWB5kXYHaQVYILTLL2werYI8WhIUSBXtlRuMrGNhpVbVFgFziLOWnI0sIW43iANsLFOoElZAXwLPVIhBjzuJVgSiN8pVLYmEu22qxEr8ghA3yUy7MxqiqqyjHnfv9d4ly1CRA8TwCeAFbYRAy/scR7aD5YTGZa7S1ljBJYBQHmH5cOF4oEc@hzbhxH5fllHQtDfCB9F4SFpbWT6DtOvI1wzyFJSWDPBui2A191Umv1sHlJlA0ZrU2gTBc1KIttabNlyeuwz2f6QI6y/F1Ck4l9YvOVFUJrzrlXSnKeGoFar6FI2WHIMIr4UypLOeVaQImZb1ufGNXO6HrNPaP4XrxrDSDjcs3dTVars8bX/Xsj8ozTM9InMCU9adDfW48aDfT/5XxDfjzc6fHM3c2ndSzC9rzD75EvgorSj8yV7Di6fHXVKHoaOS448b3GfM@ncy48bZiX8kljkpPcba65Tg@x@3OqiiqBm1MX/MFTeLoqImv4CrMZn6VQLWebMbpFzws0OFXydU3/yj2U63TzXo@H6ebju3PZ84p/zEOlx4/PX0G).

Comment: There's actually a shorter combination with just 11 states:     California (55; 55)
    Texas (38; 93)
    Florida (29; 122)
    New York (29; 151)
    Illinois (20; 171)
    Pennsylvania (20; 191)
    Ohio (18; 209)
    Georgia (16; 225)
    Michigan (16; 241)
    North Carolina (15; 256)
    New Jersey (14; 270)

Comment: @outflak while your list has less states, the total length is [4 bytes longer](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsJADAV/pfSck79QUBSsHrx4DDZ2gyGvZBd1v35t8TgwM0stCb5rbQn10g9s@kS4Mt3ky5n2htCJaZRPd0e86GimDs10Ffdc7c2bfEkKOghiXuGsj6QzO42IkrqBA2vzf5wkstS@tR8) than my current answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.htm), 1059 bytes (270 votes)

```
0 * C r 1
1 * a r 2
2 * l r 3
3 * i r 4
4 * f r 5
5 * o r 6
6 * r r 7
7 * n r 8
8 * i r 9
9 * a r π
π * , r a
a * T r b
b * e r c
c * x r d
d * a r e
e * s r f
f * , r g
g * F r h
h * l r i
i * o r j
j * r r k
k * i r l
l * d r m
m * a r n
n * , r o
o * N r p
p * e r q
q * w r r
r * _ r s
s * Y r t
t * o r u
u * r r v
v * k r w
w * , r x
x * I r y
y * l r z
z * l r A
A * i r B
B * n r C
C * o r D
D * i r E
E * s r F
F * , r G
G * P r H
H * e r I
I * n r J
J * n r K
K * s r L
L * y r M
M * l r N
N * v r O
O * a r P
P * n r Q
Q * i r R
R * a r S
S * , r T
T * O r U
U * h r V
V * i r W
W * o r X
X * , r Y
Y * G r Z
Z * e r `
` * o r ¬
¬ * r r "
" * g r £
£ * i r $
$ * a r %
% * , r ^
^ * M r &
& * i r (
( * c r )
) * h r +
+ * i r {
{ * g r }
} * a r [
[ * n r ]
] * , r -
- * N r =
= * o r :
: * r r '
' * t r @
@ * h r #
# * _ r ~
~ * C r 
> * o r .
. * l r ?
? * i r /
/ * n r |
| * a r \
\ * , r ©
© * N r À
À * e r Á
Á * w r Â
Â * _ r Ã
Ã * J r Ä
Ä * e r Å
Å * r r Æ
Æ * s r Ç
Ç * e r È
È * y r halt
```

This will print:

```
California (55; 55)
Texas (38; 93)
Florida (29; 122)
New York (29; 151)
Illinois (20; 171)
Pennsylvania (20; 191)
Ohio (18; 209)
Georgia (16; 225)
Michigan (16; 241)
North Carolina (15; 256)
New Jersey (14; 270)
```

Or to be more precise:
`California,Texas,Florida,New York,Illinois,Pennsylvania,Ohio,Georgia,Michigan,North Carolina,New Jersey`

*Updated to reflect a later rule change - thanks @Laikoni. No byte size change.*

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?92b5459a6c9d7729d6568e08354ff8da)

Comment: The challenge states "If you are using space as a separator, then you can't include any states with spaces in the name."

Comment: @Laikoni, Thanks for the update. Wouldn't have known otherwise. Wonder if there couldn't be some feature for this site where an OP could 'ping' the answerers if there are significant changes that might affect their answers?

Comment: I was not aware that this rule was added to the challenge after you posted your answer. It would have been nice if OP informed the existing answers of this change - the 'ping' you mention is easily achieved by commenting on the answers, especially as there weren't that many.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. (From my point of view, it wasn't "adding a rule", but explicitly stating something that I thought was implicit in the use of the word "separator", but point taken.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 75 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax), 271 votes

```
ê╢G.₧¢ƒdXb╜L7äF9₧⌐Ä╚ç⌂oPrçer┬♦s4⌠╧!S∟☻ƒÆà²ÿ☼{4?àç÷Uó("Φå9dgYútY°lènÜÉ↔TI╙í↨
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=88b6472e9e9b9f645862bd4c378446399ea98ec8877f6f5072876572c2047334f4cf21531c029f9285fd980f7b343f8587f655a22822e88639646759a37459f86c8a6e9a901d5449d3a117&i=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 37 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“£+ʠṅṖḳ!⁺PUB.BJçŒṖ{ScḤ?[¢¤c}€£Y,qbẆ|»
```

A niladic Link which yields a list of characters using a space as the separator. The states have a total value of 270 (and contain no spaces themselves):

```
California    55
Texas         38
Florida       29
Pennsylvania  20
Illinois      20
Ohio          18
Georgia       16
Virginia      13
Massachusetts 11
Indiana       11
Arizona       11
Maryland      10
Colorado       9
Alabama        9
           = 270
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUgAt/9qZWxsef//4oCcwqMryqDhuYXhuZbhuLMh4oG6UFVCLkJKw6fFkuG5lntTY@G4pD9bwqLCpGN94oKswqNZLHFi4bqGfMK7//8)**

#### How?

A compressed string. After taking big hitters containing no spaces I chose states which are earlier alphabetically to keep the result shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 115 bytes

```ruby
puts"California
Texas
Florida
Nor#{s="th Carolina
New "}York
Sou#{s}Jersey
Illinois
Ohio
Georgia
Michigan
Virginia"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY1BCsJADEX3OUUZz9FVQVGoLpSCy6hpJzhMJOmgpfTsY5bvP/hPy2Op9VNmCx0mHkUzI9zohwb7JMovhLPobrU2zLHpUCVx9o2@Tdjuom@4SnG9nUiNFjgm98IGl8gCBxKd/LDnZ@QJMwzs7IlQ6x8)

Makes use of the string `"th Carolina\nNew "`

Comment: @mathjunkie. Thanks, I noticed that after posting. I also noticed that a port of  Surculose Sputum's simpler but better researched answer would be shorter than this/ But I'll leave it up as I wanted to share the Carolina/New concept.

Comment: I'm glad there are languages that manage to make use of the New/North/South duplications. I tried with JavaScript but didn't save any bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>102</s> 108 bytes (270 electoral votes)

```bash
echo \"{{Californ,Georg,Virgin}ia,Florida,Arizona,Indiana,Texas,Ohio,New\ {York,Jersey},Illinois,Michigan}\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVNCsIwEAbQq5Su5xIiKBXUjQhCNtN2TD4MMzBZ@BNy9tS3eTOX1LssyYYw1rrnjKe50lHMI93hEdrAdMjmWJl2jp8p06Qr@P9NPlzommB0kXcY6sP8RSfxIt9GU85QQ6EzloTI2sLY@wY)

*Added 6 bytes to accommodate the modification to the challenge on using a space as a separator.  The original answer was:*

```bash
echo {Californ,Georg,Virgin}ia Florida Arizona Indiana Texas Ohio New\ {York,Jersey} Illinois Michigan
```

Comment: This uses space as a separator, but also includes states with spaces in their names, which isn't valid. (I've updated the rules to clarify this). Sorry if that feels like moving the goalposts - but it doesn't seem right to call something a "separator" if you can't split on it.

Comment: I've accommodated the new rule on spaces at the cost of 6 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace), 777 bytes; 274 EV's

Outputs the states as a `j`-separated list. You read that part right.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLDsIwDDs7X@FfQ2gS3JBA4vPLujaJ244dpi6rEz@W7@P52d6v230rhQRI2v6AOA70iq3uRX3frwJs0qnd1ClAjtCOejrP@HmmDFjg2siZP1UP9MHGZKtSUzZUvTP1G65ma9nQNolGwk4iQvjgitLe9GLhWupuachGgbj6O6LGB/ivpgbT/FECjFwjVQ@CA/KkNTZDGDQW2B8wRslR43oD12WIhTNL@/XOd3xXbKX8AA)

### States

`"Arizona", "California", "Florida", "Georgia", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Michigan", "Ohio", "Pennsylvania", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia"`
List chosen using @Surculose Sputum's Python script, but modified to ignore states with spaces in their names. This was because spaces have an ascii value of `32`, and `32 - 105= -73`, so pushing it would raise the byte count by a lot (I think). I have yet to test this theory though (because when removing NY I had to add something like 4 more states), so the code may yet get smaller.

### Code

A pretty standard Whitespace answer. Pushes the names of the states minus 105 to the stack, separated by a `j`, and then runs through the stack adding back the `105` and printing the result as a character. The printing part looks something like:

```
label 0:
  push 105
  add
  printc
  jmp 0
```

`105` because the character with the most occurences is `i`, which has an ascii value of 105. Outputting as a `j` separated list because `j` has a value of `106`. I used [this](https://tio.run/##fVJNbxMxEL37V4zcQ9eiiahACEUECSGBKoHgAFzSHNysN57KtS3bYRv@fBjbGy@54Itnxu@9@bI/Ju3sq7c@nE4xyaQirGHDPwT846zkN8A/SoODCxaL98m4gH0xPysX9jV6Zwxah7HYtkdZqXduLPdX3GncS5vtbxpdvr8ra@PR/JaT8A/yVYxKVedZFrGfSep8/0JKlZFbxgY0ysonRYVyd0j@kJbpOXHmhiGqRFG0qUNL8U4ItnN9Rm62jErQKmbAS2bceDapNyidE68accWATn7YaRlafLNaLW639TEfq0ZScKHvMkzAAmoJDYBDwbyDmm5m5tNKIEh7UGbivIep3EvS3MO/rNzjUnqvbN9xf4gaOLygmkNHKEEmv7dcsP9Dcx/8kc9tNCJclSYFxeHNa3YhwTkz8kEZGmRV401vFiGQ7HvmA21mxx6fPKEpKBi7KrEuS4qzQznv7Rdl90mvWnW08ooqgvBwpDXxRqmzbO40JdLPO8S8wCDtXs0qi1tRB0vjzoENbmG9nsyLJbdX4P3B0zgYGzFpcNR/d/6KN3A9XguQEYbp7yzHgIm2SX@6Zjyd/gI) script to generate the WSA (WhiteSpace Assembly) to quickly test the offset number, and used [this IDE](http://vii5ard.github.io/whitespace/) to compile it to regular Whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 114 characters, 270 votes

```js
_=>`California,Texas,Florida,Nor${s='th Carolina,New '}York,Sou${s}Jersey,Illinois,Ohio,Georgia,Michigan,Virginia`
```

Just a straight port of Level River St's Ruby answer.