# Classify State's Senators

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

United States senators are sorted into [three classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classes_of_United_States_senators), based on what year their six-year term starts. Since each state has two senators, each state has a senator in two of the three classes.

Given a full state name and a class number (1, 2, or 3), output truthy if that state has a senator of that class, and falsey if that state does not have a senator of that class.

States with Class 1 senators:

> Arizona, California, Connecticut, Delaware, Florida, Hawaii, Indiana, Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Dakota, Ohio, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia, Wisconsin, Wyoming

States with Class 2 senators:

> Alabama, Alaska, Arkansas, Colorado, Delaware, Georgia, Idaho, Illinois, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana, Maine, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Montana, Nebraska, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, North Carolina, Oklahoma, Oregon, Rhode Island, South Carolina, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Virginia, West Virginia, Wyoming

States with Class 3 senators:

> Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana, Maryland, Missouri, Nevada, New Hampshire, New York, North Carolina, North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, South Carolina, South Dakota, Utah, Vermont, Washington, Wisconsin

#### Test Cases

```
"Rhode Island", 1 -> true
"Rhode Island", 2 -> true
"Rhode Island", 3 -> false
"California", 1 -> true
"California", 2 -> false
"California", 3 -> true
"South Dakota", 1 -> false
"South Dakota", 2 -> true
"South Dakota", 3 -> true
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>67</s> 63 bytes

```python
lambda s,l:0x764d5443a33628366/3**(hash(s)%4560%1502%43)%3+1!=l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZJfb9owEMDf@RTeQwR0SAMS2ITEw0S1lbWUqt1WTV0fjsSQU4wP@ZxC9uWZYyetNsmSf@f7f75DZXPS4/N2/vusYL/JQPBAzYanj9MkmyRJDHE8HX@Kp9MP8cVFLwfOe9yPksl0GI0mw3GUxP0ofj96N1dntmAli7l46n5WsIE9dAeiRi4CGfxDusECNAPXvACFWzIavWZBigxkFFhrmVpMS1uLl1LBEYys@Yuzwsx7fJVkdsH5yukRa1pmkPsYS6VQE/pMS50hhAKWdPT39WsZ11LbMi2qmm@oRG5NV4BaBjCVAp0FZoY0L1la691XmOa4Ax3Y1c1kgzsy1@dwwFak0gQmbZskt3Jj2jndyhfIGjqKK9gfOMfQdv3wTRqWVSut5AlTaqVfZArPZGwuFmDIdQ9vL5dQNGWtc/Re60K5SYWvWhu5I9/BndSaK/UCza/c55RJseS2/Qcq/4sfXt7if5f1DFjKIJzCkH9YyOv7pzR717xHdL/XpHl064V6Z0MRj5Kt@EeNnJJmDNqK9s62@9zpuO0RKFALA3one6OBSPqzjhAHg9q6NXIbyCLKxIPUYMnwrCsiga8GT35xRR0lkIvU7DJuxbbneYD959bj/Bc)

The states can be sorted into three disjoint categories, based on what class of senators they don't have. `hash(s)%4560%1502%43` generates a number \$0 \le k \le 42 \$ without mixing up the categories. This number is then used to get a single base-3 digit out of `0x764d5443a33628366`.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>98 ... 83</s>  79 bytes

A regex solution.

Returns a non-zero value if the state has a senator of the given class.

```javascript
s=>n=>n^=/Oh|gt|N.*D|t$|yl|[UYfv]|[Wdir]i/.test(s)?2:/^I|[ACGHKLOS]/.test(s)||3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJRb9owEMff@yksNAkydaDCWys6IdBKRiHTug5VjErXxCTXGB@yHWimfHfmxEk79rJKlvy7O9/fd/Y9wx50qHBnPkmK@HEzPOrhtbTrcdgLkiI2xaL7cVKYD0UuitX9w2a/LlbLCNUae13Dtelo73P/svfoF6vR@GY6uw3u1q@RohgcR2zIVq2RgCfYQuuclahTRwp/k6wxBalBlzwGgRtSEqvImAQpiMixlDw0GGamNCdcwAEUL/mLPYVRlXHDScUueWrjiCX5ESSVhi8ESsLqJl9GCK4Anw7VPnstY8alycI0L/mWMtTN0Tmg5A5ULkBGjrWGMMk0N6ZKn2OYYAzSsa1bk3HpqHW5djtsTMqUY5KmvmTBn1TzTgu@h6imA5vCdqcTdG2Xjq9caZ431py/YEiN9UAqrZiUSdgYFNnu4c0zgbQuK0iwygpSYV/KfVWgeExVB9@4lDoXe6h/5Xtix4X5umn/jrJ/9J3nTf8HL99Ac@6MF/fI9waScv/J1dY2XyHa36uvWYLtVMbGFbG0U8VOwqhDkhpdNKetPdtaX52dlV4SvCso7rTHduA0u7hse1eMsb9Do@4GheGqo9nwmm3sxHYuPK/7TCg77XPW9rxTpV/SafUrrf8o9d@jNHiP0uBU6fgH)

#### How?

The first regular expression matches the states with **class 1** and **class 3** senators:

```
 pattern    | states
------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Oh         | Ohio
 gt         | Washington
 N.*D       | North Dakota
 t$         | Connecticut, Vermont
 yl         | Maryland, Pennsylvania
 [UYfv]     | California, Nevada, New York, (Pennsylvania), Utah
 [Wdir]i    | Arizona, Florida, Hawaii, Indiana, Missouri, Wisconsin
```

The second regular expression matches the states with **class 2** and **class 3** senators:

```
 pattern    | states
------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ^I         | Idaho, Illinois, (Indiana1), Iowa
 [ACGHKLOS] | Alabama, Alaska, (Arizona1), Arkansas, (California1), Colorado,
            | (Connecticut1), Georgia, (Hawaii1), Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,
            | New Hampshire, North Carolina, (Ohio1), Oklahoma, Oregon, South Carolina,
            | South Dakota
```

<sup>*1: These states belong to the first group. But if they've already been identified as such by the first regular expression, this one will not be executed anyway.*</sup>

The states with **class 1** and **class 2** senators are matched by neither of them:

```
Maine, Nebraska, Massachusetts, Michigan, Delaware, Minnesota, New Jersey, Tennessee,
West Virginia, Mississippi, Virginia, Wyoming, Montana, Rhode Island, New Mexico, Texas
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

Returns a non-zero value if the state has a senator of the given class.

```javascript
s=>n=>0x3A27C2823007F077n.toString(3)[parseInt(s[8]+5+s,35)%462%255%113%56]^~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLbbtpAEIbv8xSrSAhbIQjsEqJGICGiNDQlVE3bqKJUmtiLPbHZQTtrDr3oq1PbazelN41kab@Z2fl3Dn6GDXCgcW3OFYXysBwceDBUg2Fn54@8/ti79PxOp3/T6fdV29CD0agix3fna9AsJ8o4PL9cnPXOuOX33MabC6/h9XqNbtdv9C4WP36dq8NIDMT8dJTCE6zgtCUK5MSSxp@kKkxAMXDBY0hxSVphGRlTShpCsqyUDAwGmSnMa5nCFrQs@Ca/hWGZ8U6SjmzybR5HLGgSQlxqTNIUFWH50kSFCLaACW3L8@5PGXdSmSxI9gV/oAy5vjoFVNKC3qegQsvMEMQZS2PK9CkGMUagLOd1MxmbjszFt15jbVKmLZMy1SP38knXc7qXGwgr2opbWK05Rtt24Xgv813sa2sqdxhQbX0jnZRM2sRiDJry7uHFcw1JVdYsxjJrlqT5pOyqZlpGVHbwUSrF@3QD1VY@xfnvIiZct/9A2T/61vOi/1kWM2AprbGzQ/5iIC7Or1Kv8uZLxHx71TOPkHeqImOLeJRsxFEYOSDFaKN7WuV3TxdXJyeFl1LZTilymuP8h2PRfdt0r4QQf4dG7SWmRmqHxWAolg67Ttd128@Eymm2RNN1j5W@K6vllVr/UfJeo@S/Rsk/Vjr8Bg)

The method used to transform the input string is similar to the one [described in my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204553/58563) to [this related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75125/58563). Its purpose is to solve the 3 problems we have in JS:

- no built-in hash function
- `parseInt()` breaks on non-alphanumeric characters
- only 52 bits of mantissa for Numbers (i.e. 2 distinct strings sharing the same prefix may be parsed the same way)