# Resource for generating shortest regex given a list of strings

Tags: tips, regular-expression

I'm looking for a program such that, given a finite list of strings, can find short regexes to match exactly all of them and nothing else.

Since there are multiple languages that express regexes differently, there can correspondingly be multiple regex generators. Each answer must discuss regex generation in one langauge only (or a family of languages for which there is a direct correspondence between regexes in each of them).

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, I thought the "exactly" made it clear enough. Edited.

Comment: Do you mean like matching 'dome' and 'home' with the regex `(h|d)ome`?

Comment: @Krish yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Another useful feature of such a tool would be to generate a regex that matches all strings in a list A but not any of the strings in a list B, with undefined behavior for any other input. (This is what I would have needed to optimize [this handcrafted answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204595/58563).)

Comment: @Arnauld that's more specific though. An answer to mine can give you two regexes and then do A and not B, ofcourse not optimal though

Comment: @Arnauld Writing a regexp which matches all strings in a list, and no other strings, is trivial. For instance, in Perl, you can write `my $pat = '^(' . join ("|"  => map {quotemeta $_} @list_of_strings) . '$)';` This would match all strings from the list, and no others. It's not the shortest though. Shortest regexp to match all strings in a list, and no others, sounds doable. Shortest regexp which matches all strings in a list, no strings in another, and don't care for all other strings sounds much harder.

Comment: How do the strings you want to match look like? ASCII? Unicode, and if so, in which format? If Unicode, should the single character "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE" match the two character string "LATIN SMALL LETTER A; COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT"? That is, do you match on character, or on grapheme? If not on grapheme, should you match on a normal form, or just as is?

Comment: @Abigail Depends on what the respective language natively supports as stdin, which is usually ASCII

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I'd say most languages treat file handles (any kind, including STDIN) as a stream of bytes, and it's up to the program to decide how those bytes should be interpreted.

Comment: @Abigail okay not stdin then, I mean does the language natively support unicode strings? Does it's native regex matching functionality work on these unicode strings? If no, then stick to ascii. Also it's a technicality that isn't really relevant to the question imo.

Comment: @Abigail I'm not asking someone to implement a regex functionality for unicode, only try generating regexes in langauge that already natively support regexes. So the language must support unicode matching of regexes for unicode to be part of the discussion

Comment: I don't think this challenge is as interesting as it seems at first.  Take the words `['roamer','homer','boomer']`.  The shortest such regex is `(roa|ho|boo)mer`.  But as soon as you make `boomer` plural, the shortest regex becomes `((roa|ho)mer)|boomers`.  With a realistic list of more less similar words, it will quickly devolve into a mere pipe-separated list of the provided words.

Comment: @GirkovArpa Firstly this is not a challenge, it's a meta question to help solve all the questions that benefit from regexes. The questions that do, typically use words with lots of overlap so that good regexes can exist

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.  I'm new and did not know there were non-challenge questions here.

Comment: For arbitrary input, how can you prove output is the shortest possible without bruteforcing every shorter regex as well?

Comment: @golf69 I'm sure there are proof techniques for it but I'm not necessarily looking for only those regexes that are provably shortest (I'll edit the q thanks for it). And yeah my answer is basically looking for a "smart" brute force approach only

Comment: It seems to be very hard or impossible even without golfing...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica without golfing, trivial solution is to connect all the string with "and"

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code You said _shortest_ regexes.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica so that's what golfing is. Idk what you meant without golfing

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code to write code implementing it without reducing it(code).

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica oh yeah the regex generator doesn't have to be golfed

Comment: [Seems NP-hard.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1854)

Answer (score 6):

The Machine Learning Lab at the University of Trieste, Italy, wrote a web app to solve this exact problem, available at: [Automatic Generation of Regular Expressions from Examples](http://regex.inginf.units.it/) based on "genetic programming" and published a paper about it. Based on the fact that it had to come from the Machine Learning Lab of a university in Italy, and was worth publishing a paper about, it is probably a pretty hard problem to solve. Doesn't sound like the type of question for Code Golf SE, but I'm new here, so I wouldn't be the expert on that.

Comment: Welcome to the site. That's a cool approach to regex generation. Note, though, that the app isn't guaranteed to find the shortest possible regex. From the FAQ: '3. The generated regexes look unoptimized. Why? There are some optimization which could make a given regex appear better, e.g., `[\d\d\.\d]` → `[\d\.]`. Currently, our prototype does not apply any of these optimizations.' Nor will the generated regex match only the given strings and nothing else. You are right - this is a hard problem.

Comment: I didn't look into it, but the description of the website I linked does include "old version", so maybe there is a newer version which does apply the optimizations? I seem to remember the website looking different the first time I saw it than this time around, so maybe I really did link an old one...

Comment: I believe I linked to the "Regex Generator" page, here is the "Regex Generator++" page: http://regex.inginf.units.it/ . I updated the post. I wonder if the ++ version does perform the optimizations...

Comment: I believe that the ++ version does perform the optimizations. At least, in the regex golf section - which looks more similair in its UI to the ++ version - it has a stage when it is figuring out the Regex where it says "Optimizing..."

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by searching for common subsequences in each pair of strings in the list, and then building regular expressions that include those subsequences. This would be somewhat like the [Re-Pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-Pair) algorithm, but it would build a grammar from a set of strings instead of one string.

For instance, these strings:

`["red wolf", "red fox", "gray wolf", "gray fox"]`

could be combined into two regular expressions:

`"red (wolf|fox)", "gray (wolf|fox)"`

which can be combined into one regular expression:

`"(red|gray) (wolf|fox)"`

But this problem is probably NP-complete, since it is similar to the [smallest grammar problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_grammar_problem).

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This site is for competitive challenges, not for asking and answering actual questions.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms Yes, I think this question should have been posted on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) instead of Code Golf.

Comment: Ohhhh hang on yeah you're right. Didn't notice this is tagged with [tag:tips], this would definitely be better somewhere else.